# Compare each string element in a dataframe to a list and assign it to a column, python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

How to rearrange my dataframe according to column names while searching for specific strings in cells?

My dataframe:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple pie | banana bread | orange juice | nan | nan |
| apple cookies | orange lemonade | nan | nan | nan |
| banana muffin | orange ice | berry candy | nan | nan |
| berry juice | nan | nan | nan | nan |

I want to arrange the rows according to a list of column names, which look for specific strings of text.

| apple | banana | orange | berry | lemon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple pie | banana bread | orange juice | nan | nan |
| apple cookies | nan | orange lemonade | nan | nan |
| nan | banana muffin | orange ice | berry candy | nan |
| nan | nan | nan | berry juice | nan |

I have tried to create a column/list for each fruit, searching for the right string and adding the cell if it matches, however I do not know how to iterate through the dataframe and assign values. I just get a column of Nan's.

```
col_names = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'berry', 'lemonade']
apples = np.where(df_fruits.str.contains("apple", case=False, na=False), df_fruits, np.nan)
bananas = np.where(df_fruits.str.contains("banana", case=False, na=False), df_fruits, np.nan)
etc...
```

Edit:
I got the dataframe from a csv-file, so the original data format is in rows of string: "apple pie, banana bread, orange juice, nan, nan" etc.

Comment: How do you get the input dataframe in the first place? Are you reading it in from a file? It would probably be easier to construct your expected dataframe directly rather than dissect the input dataframe and reconstruct it

Comment: @Morzt I get the input dataframe from a csv file, so originally the rows are in string format: "apple pie, babana bread, orange juice, nan, nan" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can do some re-shaping using `.unstack` and `.str.extractall`

```
pat = '|'.join(col_names)

s = df.stack()

s1 = s.to_frame('vals').join(
      s.str.extractall(f'({pat})').groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list))


out = s1.explode(0).set_index(0,append=True).reset_index(1,drop=True).unstack(-1)
```

---

```
print(out)

            vals
0          apple         banana        berry         lemonade           orange
0      apple pie   banana bread          NaN              NaN     orange juice
1  apple cookies            NaN          NaN  orange lemonade  orange lemonade
2            NaN  banana muffin  berry candy              NaN       orange ice
3            NaN            NaN  berry juice              NaN              NaN
```

---

```
# if you want to drop the level on the multi index.
out.columns = out.columns.droplevel(None)

0          apple         banana        berry         lemonade           orange
0      apple pie   banana bread          NaN              NaN     orange juice
1  apple cookies            NaN          NaN  orange lemonade  orange lemonade
2            NaN  banana muffin  berry candy              NaN       orange ice
3            NaN            NaN  berry juice              NaN              NaN
```

Comment: Good attempt. orange lemonade present in both orange and lemonade :) +1

Comment: @MohamedThasinah I don't make the rules, just following OP logic, his output didn't align with the request

Comment: Yeah I can understand that. Just for fun

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I have tried to use your method and it works really well for my purpose, but I am stuck with "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" with .unstack.

Comment: Managed to fix the bug by renaming the indexes and then grouping them before unstacking. Now it works, thanks!

out = s1.explode(0).set_index(0,append=True).reset_index(1,drop=True)
out.index.names = ['fruit_list', 'fruit_group']
out = out.groupby(['fruit_list', 'fruit_group']).vals.first().unstack(-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> 

```
list_values=[item for value in df_fruits.values for item in value]
list_series=[] 
for col in col_names:
   locals()[col+"series"]=pd.Series(map(lambda x:x*(col in str(x)),list_values)
   list_series.append(eval(col+"series"))
```

the first row is the get all your dataframe colums values into a list next we create a pandas series for every fruit type and append it into a list after we create a new data frame

> `new_df=pd.concat(list_series,axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks @to_data! This works otherwise except I lose the original row ids (e.g. apple pie on row 1, banana bread on row 2, etc).